# Issue regarding adding some SQL attribute values, and placing them along with the other distinct attribute names?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

So i'm having issues trying to get an query to add prices for duplicate names, in order to calculate the cost for each and every client.Here's how it looks like.

I am expecting it to look like this:

```
clientID    clientName       setPrize
--------------------------------------------
1               Kelly             450.99
2               Leia               10.00
3               Luka               35.23
```

I tried searching for this scenario, but i couldn't find anything to make such a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you are looking for  sum() and group by

```
 select customerID,   customerName,      sum( packPrice) packPrize
 from mytable
 group by customerID,   customerName
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't may use `clientName` (may be different after years), group records by `clientID`:

```
SELECT clientID, clientName, SUM(setPrize) FROM table GROUP BY clientID;
```